# How can I specify that an exported function should not be treated as a JSX component? (React)

Tags: reactjs

I was trying to debug a 'expected 0 arguments but got 1' error and I found out that my function is considered a JSX element, which probably causes the issue. How can I specify it is a regular function?

`export async function pay(price:number){[...] return 0}`

Above is the function I am trying to export from a .tsx file and then use it in another file like so:

`pay(10)`.

How can I do that? There is a functional component in the same .tsx file by the way.

Comment: can you share the code where you are calling it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an import problem so it considered the default export only.